# Why is Apache giving my PHP files instead of execute them after host change

Tags: php, apache, prestashop, cpanel, host

After moving our prestashop to a new host (files and mysql) and setting everything up the files are not being executing but just being downloaded as "download" with the browser.
So steps has been done when migrating

1. Exported mysql as SQL file and Imported into newly created mysql within new hosting
2. Moved all content from public_html folder as zip file to new hosting and extracted all there under new domain.
3. updated the parameters.php within Prestashop with new database name user and password
4. changed base URL in mysql
5. setup same php version as old host

I tried changing php from 5.6 to 7.0 and 7.1 with no luck, checked permissions and all ok.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Could you explain a bit more what have been migrated? You just moved it but it's the same version of code and database? Your Apache config should say to Apache to _give_ PHP code to PHP, you might have a problem on this side.

Comment: Hi anthonyb , happy to be part of the community, public_html content and mysql databse where migrated to new server under new domain,so 1. export mysql as sql and imported into newly created mysql on new host 2. move content folders from new to one 3. changed base url in mysql and after trying to run any files are being downloaded....I fairly new to the Apache config is there I way to set it with command line maybe?Or even how can I check that the apache is somehow restricting php execution....

Comment: Please update your question to give more details. Explain what you said in your previous comment, what exactly have been moved, in a list why not. Also please show us your vhost. As explain in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, the more details you give, the quicker could be the answer.

Comment: Hi I corrected the question

Comment: Thank you. You are with a new host, right? Do you have a config with it? It should enable PHP for your website, and we do not have any informations about this point.

Comment: Yes with new host , I only got cpanel access to the new host 67.225.209.185 and not familiar with setting up config on cpanel

Comment: On CPannel, do you have an item named Apache? You probably have a _Virtual Host_. Usually when we install the Apache module for PHP it automatically configures Apache. Do you have Apache with your new host?

Comment: There is only APACHE HANDLERS within cpanel menu